# iOS request timeout error while connected to cellular data provider

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm facing an issue which is very random where I get server timeout error. The problem seems to be happening only;

- On iPhoneX
- When connected to cellular data

The problem is not happening on any other device than iPhoneX and when the device is connected to wifi/hotspot. I'm not sure but after some research I found that it could be related to IPV6 and cellular data provider.

Has anyone encountered the same issue? Could anybody direct me to what might be the problem here?

Comment: Did you set a custom request timeout for session? Default is 60 seconds, does it throw error before that?

Comment: It happens when the default 60 second timeout is hit.

Comment: So, you should increase the timeout.

Comment: It's very random and happens let's say once in 25-30 requests. Otherwise I get the response within 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem? I am facing same with eSim cellular network on random based.